# Lilypond: how to restore Fingering.staff-padding?

Tags: lilypond

In all examples I saw, the only value ever assigned to `Fingering.staff-padding` is `#'()` to make fingering be placed inside the staff. What should I do to go back to placing fingering outside the staff? What was the previous value of `Fingering.staff-padding`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effects of an `\override` can be undone with a `\revert`.

In particular:
`\override Fingering.staff-padding = #'()`
can be "cancelled" with:
`\revert Fingering.staff-padding`

---

You could try a number instead of the empty list, i.e.:
`\override Fingering.staff-padding = #0`
which seems to be about right.
Or you could (of course) try a larger number if you want more padding.

If you look in the Documentation Internals [3.1.51 Fingering](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/internals/fingering), it says that the default value for fingering staff padding is `0.5`.

So:
`\override Fingering.staff-padding = #0.5`
is the way to manually reset this setting to its default value.

---

However applying `\revert` is obviously a simpler method than messing around with numbers.